# testdisk - recover partition table

Tags: linux, data-recovery, dd

I destroyed my partition table of my laptop.

Testdisk reports the below

```
Disk laptop.img - 250 GB / 232 GiB - CHS 30402 255 63 (RO)
 Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>P MS Data                   435868     456606      20739 [NO NAME]
 P MS Data                 19232600   19235479       2880 [NO NAME]
 D MS Data                 41945087   83890143   41945057
 D MS Data                 57151486  168579069  111427584
 D MS Data                 67637246  141037565   73400320
 D MS Data                151523326  193466365   41943040
 D MS Data                170617328  170618223        896
 D MS Data                170631168  170634047       2880
 D MS Data                171338232  171344405       6174 [Boot]
 D MS Data                172008235  172231918     223684 [NO NAME]
 P MS Data                193466368  214437887   20971520
 D MS Data                217321375  225321678    8000304 [root]
 D MS Data                224923646  308809725   83886080 [media]
 D MS Data                308809728  420237311  111427584
 D MS Data                418910206  481824765   62914560 [vmimages]
```

my partition table had 3 Primary Partitions.

```
 1. WinXP Home
 2. /boot
 3. LVM
```

inside LVM i had 9 or 10 LVM partitions
One of them was my home (encrypted with luks)

testdisk cant recover my partition table or any other partition.
Partitions with [P] doesnt have any useful data.

I want to use dd to extract the partitions and try to recover as many files i can.
Any ideas of how i can extract eg. the [root] lvm partition from the above testdisk report ?

I am afraid that my disk was also corrupted.

Comment: You are in trouble. How much dozens of hours or thousands of euros are you willing to spend to recover *some* of your data? It could be simpler to use backups.

Comment: 10 days before that the backup disk 1Tb was failing. The result was hardware failure. My new backup disk came two days after my laptop had crashed. Murphy Law !

Comment: Every filesystem has a "magic" set of bytes in the start. You can try to find them and then define the partitions around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okei, here is what i have done till this moment.
I really hope other people never have to read this on stressful moments.

So i need two things

```
a. partition table
b. LVM configuration.
```

are there any in my disk image ?
Search for strings at your disk image to extract any useful info.

```
# strings -t d laptop.img > laptop.img.str
```

keep in mind that this could be a very large file. For a 250Gb disk my laptop.img.str is about 60Gb !

We need to do this cause ... its much more efficient to search in a 60Gb file and not in 250Gb disk image file.

```
# head -1 /etc/lvm/backup/VG_file
```

will return something like this:

```
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.98(2) (2012-10-15): Mon Nov  5 09:10:16 2012
```

so i now that i should search for "# Generated by LVM2 version " in laptop.img.str
and i did

```
# grep -E --color '# Generated by LVM2 version ' laptop.img.str > LVM2.extracts
```

i've found a lot. Sorted my date and something like:

```
24956608512 # Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.97(2) (2012-08-07): Sat Sep 22 16:22:39 2012
```

was the result.

okei so there is something useful about lvm2 configuration.

Next step.

Almost every disk has a 512 bytes sector, so calculate it:

```
# echo 24956608512/512|bc
48743376
```

hmmm lets hope to find something interesting :

```
# dd if=laptop.img bs=512 skip=48743376 count=1
```

and in fact something very beatiful came to my screen

```
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.97(2) (2012-08-07): Sat Sep 22 16:22:39 2012

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *after* executing 'lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vg01/mmoviess'"

creation_host = "mylaptop"  # Linux mylaptop 3.5.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Aug 26 09:14:51 CEST 2012 x86_64
creation_time = 1348320159  # Sat Sep 22 16:22:39 2012
```

changing count from 1 to 4 and i now have my entire LVM2 conf file. Backup somewhere safe and continue with the partition table.

I now that i had three (3) primary partitions. sda1 - sda2 - sda3
So i thought to search for them at laptop.img.str.

Finally and with the above steps i found this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b13ab

   Device Boot      Start         End Blocks   Id System
/dev/sda1   *          20    41945087    20972534    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        41945088    42469375      262144   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        42469376   488397167   222963896   8e  Linux LVM
```

Testdisk report didnt help at all.

hexdump became my new best friend !

also useful: grep with -a -b parameters and losetup with offset paramater !
no extra software - no extra installs - nothing.

just basic cmds with powerful use.

Comment: Once you have the partition offsets and types, how did you 'reconstruct' the partition table (so that original partition and data would become accessible again)?